# how do you route a react app together by using redux data?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Coming from an angular background where I would use ui-router in order to do this and currently learning about how to use react.js and redux. this is last thing I need to understand about react and redux. What the method to connect two components by their data? Basically what I want is when someone click on {article.title} as a link. It will go to the article component where it will display all of the information with that array like author, article, etc important information like on a news site. how do I code both the list and article part so they are connected and connect it to the list part via routes. Hope the question is clear enough to understand. Also the article part is getting data from the my backend fine so that is working currently.

data set

```
[{"_id":"58c71df9f7e4e47f1fe17eeb","article":"words words","author":"Jason","date":"1/2/2014","title":"my article","__v":0}, aka bunch more data]
```

the list component

```
  import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import { fetchArticle } from '../../actions/fashionActions';

@connect((store) => {
    return {

        articles: store.articles.articles,
    };
})
export default class FashionArticle extends React.Component {


    fetchArticle() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchArticle())
    }

    render() {
        const { articles } = this.props;

        if (!articles.length) {
            return <button onClick={this.fetchArticle.bind(this)}>load Articles</button>
        }

        const mappedArticles = articles.map(article =>
<div>
    <Link to={`fashionArticle/${articles.id}`}>{articles.title}</Link>
</div>
        )

        return <div>
            <h1>List of Fashion Article</h1>
            <ul>{mappedArticles}</ul>
        </div>
    }
}
```

the article component

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import { fetchArticle } from '../../actions/fashionActions';

export default class FashionArticle extends React.Component {


}
```

routes

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
      <IndexRoute component={HomePage}></IndexRoute>
        <Route path="about" name="about" components={AboutPage}/>
        <Route path="fashionlist" name="fashionlist" components={FashionList} /> // the list of data
        <Route path="fashionarticle/:id" name="fashionarticle" components={FashionArticle}/> // what the click on the will go to
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

Comment: There are two FashionArticles. Where is FashionList

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to display fashion article when user clicks on a link,  So Use `Link` from `react-router` as `<Link to={'/fashionArticle/${articles.id}'>Visit Fashion Article</Link>`. Now, you already have article data in store so you can easily fetch and display data on UI from the store.

Comment: basically I want the link to show {article.title} and when you click it. It goes to the fashionArticle with all the information from title, author, summary, etc. Anyways I made changes to the list component adding    <div>
               <Link to='/fashionArticle/${articles.id}'>{article.title}</Link>
            </div> It gives me my first article from my data which i want but it not going to the fashionArticle page and the url comes back as http://localhost:3000/#/fashionArticle/${articles.id} not what i want but getting there.

Comment: In Link, You need to use backticks when using template string literals, so change 'fashionArticle/${articles.id}' to `\`fashionArticle/${articles.id}\``.So, finally your link should look like, `<Link to={\`fashionArticle/${articles.id}\`}>{articles.title}</Link>`

Comment: doing  <Link to={`fashionArticle/${articles.id}`}>{articles.title}</Link>causes the link to entirely not show up on the list component...

Comment: Can you please update the question with your current code?

Comment: sorry i'm dumb, it article.title not articles.title

Comment: now the last thing is how do I set up the article part so the data show up on the page after clicking the link on the list component